# iPython: How to sort by monthname and fix KeyError in Python Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

What is the best way to plot a bar graph that is ordered by month name? I am trying to sort the dataframe by monthname and plot a bargraph. However, I've encountered an error with this code:

```
month_df = tweets_df.groupby(['Month'])[["Tweet"]].count()
month_df

month_df = month_df.sort_values(by="Month")
month_df

plt.rc('figure', figsize=(16, 8))
plt.bar(month_df['Month'], year_df['Tweet'])
plt.xticks(month_df['Month'])
plt.ylabel('Number of Tweets')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.show()
```

Here is the dataframe I am trying to create a barplot with:

| Month | Tweet |
| --- | --- |
| April | 3105 |
| August | 2315 |
| December | 3797 |
| February | 2183 |
| January | 2047 |
| July | 2045 |
| June | 2268 |
| March | 2954 |
| May | 3074 |
| November | 2136 |
| October | 1837 |
| September | 1769 |

Please see below error I've encountered:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
F:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Month'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-ce7a745ed49b> in <module>
      1 plt.rc('figure', figsize=(16, 8))
----> 2 plt.bar(year_df['Month'], year_df['Tweet'])
      3 plt.xticks(year_df['Month'])
      4 plt.ylabel('Number of Tweets')
      5 plt.xlabel('Month')

F:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

F:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Month'
```

Comment: You are using month_df and then year_df. Is it supposed to be the same dataframe? Does column Month exist in year_df?

Comment: It is supposed to be month_df only. Thanks for clarification @Mattravel

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, I am assuming the plot uses month_df, not year_df. For the data provided, you will need to take care of two things.

1. Convert the month text column to datetime as this will help python understand that you have a datetime column using pandas `datetime`
2. When you plot, tell python to show only month using `%B`

I am reading the data from an excel file... rest is updates to your code.

```
## Read data to month_df
month_df=pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

## Convert the Month column to datetime format. Note %B means you are providing full month, as is your case
month_df['Month']=pd.to_datetime('2023' + month_df['Month'], format='%Y%B')

## Your code
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(16, 8))
plt.bar(month_df['Month'], month_df['Tweet'], width =10) ##Changed to month, added width
plt.xticks(month_df['Month'])
plt.ylabel('Number of Tweets')
plt.xlabel('Month')

## Added to convert the tick labels from default to show only Month (%B)
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
# Set the locator
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
# Specify the format - %B ... use %b is you want short form like Jan, Feb
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%B')
X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
# Specify formatter
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)

plt.show()
```

Plot created is ...

[image]